# erb indenting: should you indent html inside ruby control structures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indentation, erb

When it comes to indentation, which is more prevalent

```
<% if something? %>
    Test
<% else %>
    Test
<% end %>
```

or

```
<% if something? %>
Test
<% else %>
Test
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is a very personal-choice kind of question. I tend to indent but only by 2 spaces, because indenting makes the control-structure clear and easy to see... but everyone will have their own ideas on this...

Comment: Use first one. Concept of indentation is for making code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Use the first one.  You'll stay consistent from pure Ruby to ERB to JS to Coffeescript.  Much easier to follow with the eyes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use the first option as the concept of indentation is for making the code more readable and in the coffee-script it is must.